# How to use user input to select a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, variables

I want to send a number of predefined queries to mysql.
i will use the variable defined internally by using the externally inputted variable as below.
But not good.

```
[testuser@testserver work]$ cat test1.sh 
#!/bin/sh

query1='select * from mysql.user limit 2;'
query2="select * from mysql.user limit 2;"

echo $1
echo "$1"
#mysql -uuser-p -e "$1"
```

this is result

```
[testuser@testserver work]$ sh test3.sh query1 
query1
query1
```

but i want result

```
[testuser@testserver work]$ sh test1.sh  query1 
select * From mysql.user limit 1
```

how to modify this bash scrpit?

Comment: U could use `echo "${!1}"` syntax!

Comment: Question: what is your ultimate goal here? Indirection is generally not the way to go. If you just want to define the variables `query1` and `query2`, you can use `source test1.sh; echo query1`, if you just want to retrieve it, I would use a `case` statement.

Comment: @user1819769 : `$1` is the first parameter to your script. You pass _query1_ as parameter, so of course _query1_ is printed by the `echo` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

query1='select * from mysql.user limit 2;'
query2="select * from mysql.user limit 2;"

echo "${!1}"
#mysql -uuser-p -e "${!1}"
```

But you could:

```
#!/bin/bash

queries=('select * from mysql.user limit 2;'
        "select * from mysql.user limit 2;")

echo "${queries[$1]}"
#mysql -uuser-p -e "${queries[$1]}"
```

Then run `./test 0` or `./test 1`.

Or even

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A queries=$'(
    [query1]=\047select * from mysql.user limit 2;\047
    [query2]="select * from mysql.user limit 2;")'

echo "${queries[$1]}"
#mysql -uuser-p -e "${queries[$1]}"
```

Note: Syntax `$'....\047...\047...'` is a trick for using simple quotes in quoted string.

Then run `./test3 query1`.

Comment: So $1 needs now to be numeric because we use an array?

Comment: @stephanmg In my second purpose, yes!

Comment: @F.Hauri: I'd wanted to suggest this too, because if he will have more queries this will somehow clutter the code.

Answer (score 1):

Can also use a case statment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


case "$1" in
    --query1)
        echo "select * from mysql.user limit 1;"
        ;;
    --query2)
        echo "select * from mysql.user limit 2;"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "unkown option"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

then run something like: `./test --query1`

Comment: Double dash are not needed!  `case $1 in query1 ) ...;; query2) ...;;esac` will work too!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

query1='query 1'
query2='query 2'

eval var="$"$1
echo $var
```

Edit: This uses eval which should be avoided, which might be unsafe if you don't trust the data. There is for Bash scripts variable indirection via the mechanism "${!VARNAME}", so you can use "${!1}".

Comment: Avoid using `eval`!!

Comment: Possibly interesting if not writing Bash but Sh scripts: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425024/combining-a-variable-value-and-string-to-form-another-variable